# Grails dynamic drop down Using remoteFunction is not working

Tags: ajax, grails, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a dynamic drop down menu in Grails work. The second drop down is not populated after the select on the first drop down.

Here's my code on my _form gsp:

```
<g:select name="department" from="${MCM.MGDepartment.list(sort:'dep')}" values="${MGMatricesSRFApproversInstance?.department?.id}" optionKey="id" noSelection="${[null: 'Select One...']}"
             onchange="${remoteFunction (controller: 'mGMatricesSRFApprovers', action: 'findJobTitleForDepartment', params: '\'department.id=\' + this.value', update: 'jobTitleSelection')}"/>              
<td id="jobTitleSelection">
    <select>
        <option>Select One...</option>
        <g:select name="jobTitle.id" from="${MCM.MGJobTitle.list()}" optionKey="id"/>
    </select>
</td>
```

Code in my controller:

```
def findJobTitleForDepartment = {
  println "findJobTitleForDepartment"
  def job = MGDepartment.get(params.department.id)
  render(template: 'jobTitleSelection', model:  [mGJobTitle: job.mGJobTitle])
}
```

In my create header i have:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery"/>
```

Is there a way to make the dynamic drop down work?

Comment: what result HTML do you get for your `_form.gsp`?

Comment: It display two drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ,Exactly

like this one :

```
 <g:select name="departmentId" id="department" from="${MCM.MGDepartment.list(sort:'dep')}" values="${MGMatricesSRFApproversInstance?.department?.id}" optionKey="id" noSelection="${[null: 'Select One...']}"
                 onchange='loadJobTitles();'>    
 <g:select id="jobTitle" name="jobTitleid" from="${[]}" optionKey="id"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">        

      function loadJobTitles(init)
            {
                var root="${resource()}";
                var departmentid=document.getElementById('department').value;               

                var url = root+'/Departemnt/findJobTitleForDepartment?departementId='+departmentid;

                jQuery('#jobTitle').load(url);
            }
            </script>
```

//and you findJobTitleForDepartment should be implemented like this

```
 def findJobTitleForDepartment() {
    def html="" 
    def jobtitle = null
    def dep = null
    def boolean empityString = true

      if(params?.departementid!='null') {

            dep =Department.get(params?.departementid?.toLong())
            jobtitle= dep.mGJobTitle.sort{it.name} // you can ignore sort here //just list



            jobtitle.each {
                if(empityString)
                {
                    empityString = false
                    html=html + "<option selected='selected' value=\'null\'></option>"
                    html=html + "<option value=\'${it.id}\'> ${it}</option>"
                }
                else
                    html=html + "<option value=\'${it.id}\'> ${it}</option>"

} //if end upper root

render html
            }
```

Comment: I tried this code but it didn't solve my problem. I place a print message inside the findJobTitleForDepartment() but it didn't print the message.

Comment: @jeka am sorry my bad ,i have edited the code on change Event of the above dropdown call loadJobTitles(); and under javascript definition the function name should be loadJobTitles anything let me know ..

Comment: why there is two departmentid variable on loadJobTitles?

Comment: I have an error the value of departmentid is null when called in findJobTitleForDepartment.

Comment: @jeka I have written it please it was becuse you refer params?.departementid insteadOf params?.departmentId , you see the name of your selectBox that is we are trying to do on findJObtTittles....

Comment: So i can use departmentid = "${MGMatricesSRFApproversInstance?.department?.id}" instead of departmentid = document.getElementById('department').value;? But why in the findJobTitleForDepartment params?.departementid is null?

Comment: departementId --this is the exact name from your  params (params?.departementId)  that's why?i hope your question will be resolved by now. don't forget to accept as you answer:)

Comment: @Jeka look below an answer please

Comment: another question please. The dropdown works properly but when I applied it to a different pair of dropdown the controller action is not called. How to hear from you. Thanks.

Comment: @I didn't understand question ? more than two cascades?

Comment: no. I have another dropdowns for application and document type. When I apply this solution the action in controller is not called.

Comment: @Jeka create a new question for that in detail ,i think that is easy to discuses...

Comment: Hi how can the selected value on the second dropdown be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

## 1 an Easy Method

Define on change and post it using ajax ,then return select box from controller DONE! 
How ?

```
<g:select name="department" id="DepartmentId" from="${MCM.MGDepartment.list(sort:'dep')}" values="${MGMatricesSRFApproversInstance?.department?.id}" optionKey="id" noSelection="${[null: 'Select One...']}"
             onchange="${remoteFunction (controller: 'mGMatricesSRFApprovers', action: 'findJobTitleForDepartment', params: '\'department.id=\' + this.value', update: 'jobTitleSelection')}"/>              
<td id="jobTitleSelection">
    <select>
        <option>Select One...</option>
        <g:select name="jobTitle.id" id="jobID" from="${[]}" optionKey="id"/>
    </select>
</td>
```

Use g:javascript and define ajax jquery post

```
<g:javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#territory").change(function() {
            var depValue = $("#DepartmentId").val();
            $.ajax({
             url:"${resource()}"+"/Department/getJobByDepartment",
             data:"id="+this.value,
             method:"POST",
             cache:false,
             success:function(result) {
             $("#jobID").html(result);
             $("#jobID").val(depValue );
             $("#jobID").trigger('change');
             }             
            });     
        }); 
});

</g:javascript>
```

## finally controller

```
def getJobByDepartment(params){

  //check for null selection and add the nessary code but if not null

  println "findJobTitleForDepartment"
  def departemnt= MGDepartment.get(params?.DepartmentId)
  render g.select(from: departement.jobs, id:"jobId",name:"job",noSelection:['null':'']])

}
```

Done and I expect some points :)!!! Daniel

Comment: :) you must be kidding...how about then ?

Comment: no im not. I print a message inside the javascript and its not printing. Its not going inside the javascript.

Comment: @hey first make sure your page imported the jquery library in your layout file , then test some alert('test'); on sample javascript function if those work there no'n this doesn't work DO!

Answer (score 0):

If you change you response holder to a div instead of td then I think you should be able to get the result something like:

```
    <g:select name="department" from="${MCM.MGDepartment.list(sort:'dep')}" optionValue="dept" optionKey="id" noSelection="${[null: 'Select One...']}"
             onchange="${remoteFunction (controller: 'mGMatricesSRFApprovers', action: 'findJobTitleForDepartment', params: '\'department.id=\' + this.value', update: 'jobTitleSelection')}"/>              
<td >
<div id="jobTitleSelection">

        <g:select name="jobTitle.id" from="${MCM.MGJobTitle.list()}" optionKey="id"/>

</div>
</td>
```

I assume you have Jquery available on your page, and you are getting response status ok from your ajax request.

Comment: The code just ruin my page layout because of the div, but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: It was just a place holder, you can just try it out, for ajax to work, and then layout can be adjusted accordingly, are you getting response from the controller(can be checked in the firebug, on change event)?? or change your select dropdown as in the updated answer above

Comment: You must have some strange layout as adding a div ruined your layout
:)

Comment: hows your jobTitleSelection template looks like??